# How to set up WebStorm by separating files hierarchy with lines (picture example in description)

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

My current files hierarchy view is:

[image]

I want to set up this view like this:

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preferences > Appearance > Show tree indent guides

Or search for 'Show tree indent guides' with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Yeah! They did it! Buying Webstorm worth it's money!